# Modify VM in OVA

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, ovf, virtual-appliances

I have an OVA that contains a vApp with 9 VMs inside. I need to make a change to the drive contents of one of the VMs in the OVA. The OVA takes a very long time to export from vSphere (24 hours). Is there any way to modify the VM in the OVA without having to re-export the whole vApp?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ovftool](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/ovf410/ovftool-410_userguide.pdf) documentation , there is no such command.

Ova is a big "archive" and can be opened with 7zip and extracted.
But if you modify the extracted files (ovf) , you'll need to [calculate](https://frgtech.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/uncompress-a-vmware-ova-and-modify-its-vm-version/) the checksums to be able to deploy.

I don't know if "repacking" the ova with 7zip is valid

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly untar and tar back with no issues.

This worked for me:
https://gist.github.com/goodjob1114/9ededff0de32c1119cf7